# remove specific object from MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb-query

I'm trying to remove from MongoDB collection an object (not document) that meets specific value condition, in this case -  "Accessible" : "null" - while keeping other instances of this objects. I tried db.collection.update({}, {$unset: { "Accessible":"null"}}, false, true) but it removed all objects with "Accessible" key.Thanks in advance
My MongoDB collection before update

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52e5f09e8f3d99e1046abccc"),
    "Name" : "Skyline",
"Accessible" : "Y"

}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52e5f09e8f3d99e1046abccd"),
    "Name" : "Highland",
"Accessible" : "null"

}
```

Desired result:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52e5f09e8f3d99e1046abccc"),
    "Name" : "Skyline",
"Accessible" : "Y"

}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52e5f09e8f3d99e1046abccd"),
    "Name" : "Highland"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first identify the documents you wish to update and then unset that specific field:

```
db.collection.update(
    {"Accessible" : "null"}, 
    {$unset: { "Accessible" : ""}},
    { multi: true }
)
```

Further documentation on $unset operator:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/

Comment: Please mark answer as correct, if you feel it was :)